# Where does $f(r,\varphi,\theta)=(r\sin{\theta}\cos{\varphi},r\sin{\theta}\sin{\varphi},r\cos{\theta})$ have a locally differentiable inversion?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

$$f(r,\varphi,\theta)=(r\sin{\theta}\cos{\varphi},r\sin{\theta}\sin{\varphi},r\cos{\theta})$$

$$f:(0,\infty)\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$$

How can I find out on which points $f$ is a local Diffeomorphism and for which is it not?

Comment: Are you sure you wrote that correctly?  $f(r,\varphi,\theta)$ doesn't depend on $\varphi$, and the $x$ and $y$ coordinates are the same? If so, the answer is rather obvious.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The actual function looks like this $f(r,\varphi,\theta)=(r\sin{\theta}\cos{\varphi},r\sin{\theta}\sin{\varphi},r\cos{\theta})$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If you know Inverse Function Theorem then it is enough to check where rank$[Df(p)] = 3$.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to look that up. Would that be enough to find all these points you think?

Comment: Inverse Function Theorem tells you the points in which f is a local diffeomorphism.